# Manjaro 18 won't INSTALL

Tags: linux, networking, installation, manjaro

Before anything else, I should mention that my Linux knowledge is rather small and I'm not a native English speaker, so please have patience with me.

When I try to install Manjaro 18 (Gnome), it always gets stuck at 92% (misc postinstall). From what I've been able to find, it probably hangs at `pacman -Sy`, but I don't know how to check if that's true.

Either way, by the time the installer gets to this stage, internet stops working... mostly. When I try to open a new tab in Firefox and open let's say Google, it doesn't load, BUT when I tried to determine at which exact point the internet connection stops working by using http://startrinity.com/InternetQuality/InternetConnectionMonitor.aspx , the site never showed any down time. This leads me to believe that there's a problem with DNS connection or something like that.

I tried cancelling the installation and then booting up the partially installed Manjaro anyway. What I got, was what seemed like a fully working install of Manjaro, except that I was experiencing the same connection problem as described above.

What should I do to get Manjaro Gnome properly installed?

Comment: It is hard to solve in a Q&A session. If you have Manjaro installed and working you can try some steps. Some commands may help `ip`, `ping`. Try to edit `/etc/resolv.conf`. Check NetworkManager service etc. [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/installation_guide) may help.

Comment: Alright, just tried connecting via wifi and disabling wired connection out of pure curiosity... That solved it, but I'd really like to use wired instead.

Comment: `ping 8.8.8.8` is useful for checking whether you have Internet connectivity, and it doesn’t require that you have working DNS.